# Sidebar is in the wrong place when desktop, but not when mobile

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I have a problem with the website I'm currently making for my art
theyoungillustrations.com

I have absolutely no experience in coding, so please explain like I'm five

I'm altering a excisting code, but I experience a problem with the sidebar. Because I made a banner (at the top), the sidebar is currently under it and I can't find out how I can fix that without ruining the mobile-sidebar.

This here seems to be the target, but the style-ing part is the one I'm unsure of.

```
 <div id="sidebar" class="{select:Header Text Case} ">        

<div class="inner animated slow">
    <div class="wrap">

        <nav class="sidebar-navigation cl">
            <ul>

                {block:IfHomeLink}
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                {/block:IfHomeLink}

                {block:HasPages}
                    {block:Pages}
                    <li> <a href="{URL}">{Label}</a></li>
                    {/block:Pages}
                {/block:HasPages}

            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>
</div>
</div>


<div id="header" class="{select:Header Text Case} ">
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner">

        <div class="logo">
            {block:ifnotlogoimage}
                <a href="/" title="{lang:Home}">{Title}</a>
            {/block:ifnotlogoimage}
            {block:iflogoimage}
                <a href="/"><img src="{image:Logo}" alt="logo" /></a>
            {/block:iflogoimage}
        </div>        

        <nav class="navigation cl">
            <ul>
                {block:HasPages}
                    {block:Pages}
                    <li> <a href="{URL}">{Label}</a></li>
                    {/block:Pages}
                {/block:HasPages}


                &nbsp;
            </ul>
        </nav>

        </div>
        </div>



        <div class="sidebar-toggle">
            Menu
        </div>

        <div class="close-mobile-modal">
            <svg width="16px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                    <path d="M7.172,10 L3.642,6.47 L0.102,2.93 L2.928,0.1 L10,7.173 L17.07,0.103 L19.9,2.93 L12.827,10 L19.897,17.07 L17.07,19.9 L10,12.827 L2.93,19.897 L0.1,17.07 L7.173,10 L7.172,10 Z"></path>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then I have this:

```
 }
    #sidebar h3 {
        margin-bottom:20px;
        color:{color:Header Text};
        font-size:13px;
    }
    #sidebar-navigation {
       color:{color:Header Text};
        background:{color:Header Background};
        font-size:{text:Header Size};
    }
```

But I'm clueless. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to add a breakpoint for various devices ,you can take help of this url :https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: In concrete, how do I make sure that the sidebar isn't fixed at the complete top of the page when in desktop-interface-mode, even if I added that query? Because it seems to me that if you add that, it stil doesn't know where to place the thing. (I hope you understand what I'm saying)